# What are Doxygen SERVER_BASED_SEARCH requirements/dependencies?

Tags: doxygen

I'm having the same problem [reported here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48440476/8419134):

The Doxygen server side search works on my old web site. It does not work on the new web site (new web hosting provider). I've narrowed the problem down somewhat...

The server side search works on original site with PHP version 5.5 and on another site with PHP version 5.3. The new site uses PHP 7.1.

Also, I was able to change one of the sites from 5.5 to 7.1. That caused the Doxygen server side search to fail in the same way. However, the precise reasons are inconclusive, since some PHP extensions are missing in my PHP 7.1 panel. So I have these questions:

1. What versions of PHP is Doxygen's server side search expected to work with?
2. Are there any PHP extensions that Doxygen's server side search depends on?

[Questions to which I can find no answers in Doxygen documentation nor on it's mailing lists and such.]